# best way to attach an event handler to element in jQuery by performance

Tags: jquery, performance, event-handling

**What is the best way to attach an event handler to element in jQuery by performance?**

All elements that I want to attach an event handler to them, are static
and we don't have any generated and dynamically created elements:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="qux"></div>
```

I want to attach `click` event handler to all them separately, I have three options.

---

### I. Attaching event handler directly

In this classic method, I will attach the event handler directly to the elements:

```
$('.foo').on('click', f);
$('.bar').on('click', g);
$('.qux').on('click', h);
```

---

### II. Attaching event handler to parent multiple times

In this method, instead of previous one, I'll attach the event handler to a parent one, multiple times, for each element:

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo', f);
$('body').on('click', '.bar', g);
$('body').on('click', '.qux', h);
```

---

### III. Attaching event handler to parent just one time

This method is just like previous method, except one difference.
I'll attach the event handler only one time, and I will check the
desired selectors in the handler itself:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target);

         if ($elem.is('.foo')) { f(); }
    else if ($elem.is('.bar')) { g(); }
    else if ($elem.is('.qux')) { h(); }
});
```

---

I want to know which one is the best as performance?

Comment: What tell jsperf concerning this?  http://jsperf.com/test-so-1

Comment: If you're worried about performance (why?), don't use jQuery.

Comment: If 3 is the real number, I wouldn't worry about performances, rather with maintainabiliy/readability. Can you be more specific about your concern ?

Comment: @roasted Can you tell me more about jsperf? And maybe post an answer? I runned the test twice, and it shows the third one as fastest.

Comment: The third option is the fastest one for binding but its not for firing event. These are two different things.

Comment: In the second option (which I don't recommend, as it makes all events bubble up to the `body` level before firing), you should be chaining your calls rather than selecting `body` 3 times: `$('body').on(...).on(...).on(...);`

Answer (score 2):

***Decided to move it from comment to answer.***
IMO, the operation of event binding does not affect performance much. What should be taken into account are operations, that *are executed in the handler*. That is why the **third option** is probably the worst.

The **second option**, AFAIK, is commonly used as *event delegation*. Mostly, in cases when you want to bind an event to the element, that would be created in the future, i.e. via AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', '.futureElement', alert);
$.post("someurl", {data: someData}, function () {
   //create element with class .futureElement
});
```

The **first one** is the common way of binding event with jQuery, therefore the fastest one of the presented.

Answer (score 0):

Your third solution is definitely the worst one, as it checks element's class whenever click event is fired.

The bottleneck here is jQuery selector parsing, so the first solution is the most efficent and readable one.

Answer (score 0):

Let me disagree with the other answers.

Even tests here http://jsperf.com/test-so-1 say that the last option is the fastest. But i can try to explain why.

In this case:

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo', f);
```

we use a standart jquery way to bind delegated events. We bind an event to the `body` and ask jQuery to check it against `.foo` selector. Each event has a property `e.target`, which actually initiated the event. But event bubbles up the DOM so our `.foo` selector can match one of the parents of `e.target`. So jQuery must do additional traversing e.g. find all parents of `e.target` and check it against `.foo` selector.

It the 3d option we directly check only `e.target`.

If `.foo` selector is close to the `body` then there is no much difference in performance. But if `.foo` selector is deep inside the DOM tree jQuery have to traverse a lot of parents of `e.target`.

Tests that demostrate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/xDyuJ/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/xDyuJ/2/

You can see it measures only events execution. The 3d case is more then twice faster. The gap will change relatively to the position on the elements in the DOM tree.

Comment: jsPerf does not execute the function in the handler. The binding will be faster, definitely. But the execution and readability are the worst.