# Is it considered bad practice to use document.on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it considered bad practice to bind events with `document.on()`?

I'd imagine that it'd be much more efficient to bind events directly to dom elements.

I ask because I'm trying to figure out how to implement some Javascript functionality and I want to avoid making widespread use of `document.on()` if it's inefficient.

Comment: read my answer to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896435/best-way-to-attach-an-event-handler-to-element-in-jquery-by-performance/16897303#16897303

Comment: It explains it all in the documentation for on. Read the section "[Event performance](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance)"!  From the docs: *Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance...*

Comment: I can only think of 2 fairly basic reasons for binding events to the document, to monitor it (i.e. Ready/Load/Scroll events) and to deactivate another element when you click anywhere on a page (because of bubbling). Not quite sure what else you're asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid it if possible. You have to realize that almost every event bubbles up to the top. Then jQuery has to query the target with your selector; probably a different one for each event bound this way. That can add up.

I have personally been confronted with legacy code that made heavy use of the now gone function `.live()`. As can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422110/880984), that is equivalent to binding to `document`.

We ended up having sometimes multiple second latency on click events because of this. After fixing the unnecessary `live()` bindings because they were causing some obscure bugs, we ended up with massive usability improvements.

You also can't suppress events at that point because the default action has possibly already taken place. You should bind more specifically if you can. And in all likelihood, you can.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally NOT recommended to bind delegated methods bound to the document or body objects becouse it can cause performance issues. The issue is that if you get lots of delegated events all bound to the same object, then every time an event occurs and it bubbles up to this object, jQuery has to compare the originating selector to a lot of different selectors to see which handler to call.

It is much better to bind delegated events to a parent object that is as close to the actual target objects as possible.